# Split text with quotes into sentences using BreakIterator Java

Tags: java

I try to split paragraph contain quotation into sentences using BreakIterator Java.

This is my paragraph contain quotation that i want to split :

> "People are now getting smarter and more critical. They know which are
>   eligible to choose, which one pan, where the gold," he said. About
>   strategies for coping with the upcoming elections, Edi said, it was
>   still awaiting the provision.

This is my code :

```
public class SplitParagraph {
public static void main(String[] args){
    String paragraph = "\"People are now getting smarter and more critical. They know which are eligible to choose, which one pan, where the gold,\" he said. About strategies for coping with the upcoming elections, Edi said, it was still awaiting the provision.";
    BreakIterator iterator = BreakIterator.getSentenceInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
    iterator.setText(paragraph);
    int start = iterator.first();
    int i=1;
    for (int end = iterator.next();end != BreakIterator.DONE; start = end, end = iterator.next()) {
        System.out.println("Sentence "+i+" : "+paragraph.substring(start,end));
        i++;
    }
}}
```

Output Program :

Sentence 1 : "People are now getting smarter and more critical. 
Sentence 2 : They know which are eligible to choose, which one pan, where the gold," he said. 
Sentence 3 : About strategies for coping with the upcoming elections, Edi said, it was still awaiting the provision.

> The output program is incorrect because the paragraph only contain 2
>   sentences. Not 3 sentences.

The correct output program must like this :

Sentence 1 : "People are now getting smarter and more critical. They know which are eligible to choose, which one pan, where the gold," he said. 
Sentence 2 : About strategies for coping with the upcoming elections, Edi said, it was still awaiting the provision.

Any idea for my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Just split your input according to the below regex,

```
"(?<=\\.)\\s+(?=(?:\"[^\"]*\"|[^\"])*$)"
```

This matches one or more spaces exists just after to the dot which was not present inside the double quotes.

`(?<=\\.)` - Positive lookbehind which looks just to all the dots.

`\\s+` - Matches one or more space characters.

`(?=...)` - Positive lookahead which asserts that the match must be followed by,

`(?:\"[^\"]*\"|[^\"])*` - Any double quoted block like `"foobar"` or any character but not of double quotes, zero or more times.

`(?:\"[^\"]*\"|[^\"])*$` And then it must reach the line end. This won't match space in `"foo. bar"` string because after the space there exists a single double quotes not the double quoted block.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/uN4lT5/2)

```
String s = "\"People are now getting smarter and more critical. They know which are eligible to choose, which one pan, where the gold,\" he said. About strategies for coping with the upcoming elections, Edi said, it was still awaiting the provision.";
String parts[] = s.split("(?<=\\.)\\s+(?=(?:\"[^\"]*\"|[^\"])*$)");
for(String i: parts)
{
System.out.println(i);
}
```

**Output:**

```
"People are now getting smarter and more critical. They know which are eligible to choose, which one pan, where the gold," he said.
About strategies for coping with the upcoming elections, Edi said, it was still awaiting the provision.
```

**OR**

```
String s = "\"People are now getting smarter and more critical. They know which are eligible to choose, which one pan, where the gold,\" he said. About Mr. Mrs. strategies for coping with the upcoming elections, Edi said, it was still awaiting the provision.";
String parts[] = s.split("(?<!Mrs?\\.)(?<=\\.)\\s+(?=(?:\"[^\"]*\"|[^\"])*$)");
for(String i: parts)
{
System.out.println(i);
}
```

Output:

```
"People are now getting smarter and more critical. They know which are eligible to choose, which one pan, where the gold," he said.
About Mr. Mrs. strategies for coping with the upcoming elections, Edi said, it was still awaiting the provision.
```

Comment: Purpose of  BreakIterator is to avoid many traps while splitting like in "Mr. & Mrs. Smith". Regex may not be best solution here. BTW I am not downvoter.

Comment: but op failed to mention about this issue in his question. see https://regex101.com/r/uN4lT5/3

Comment: @Pshemo : no problem. My paragraph is indonesian language. Not user Mr. & Mrs

Comment: @AvinashRaj  : i want ask to you. I have a second problem. how to split sentence by \n or \n\n 

example text : 

My name is Zulkifli. 
I'm from Indonesia. 

I love Java. 

Result after split : 
Sentence 1 : My name is Zulkifli. 
Sentence 2 : I'm from Indonesia. 
Sentence 3 : I love Java.

Comment: use `[\\n\\r]+` regex to split the string according to one or more line breaks